# iOS – Animation glitch with UIToolbar

Tags: objective-c, animation, uitoolbar

I'm getting a "weird" animation glitch when I add a `UIToolbar` to the view. I'm animating the UIToolbar so it slides up from the bottom together with either a `UIPickerView` or a `UIDatePicker`. At first I see it's sliding up but after the animation is finished it quickly disappears. This happens when I slide down (animating the UIPickerView to slide down off the screen) and right after that I have another UIPickerView slide up.

I noticed that if I set a delay (`- performSelector...`) on the slide up call for 0.3 seconds it will display the UIToolbar properly (anything less than 0.3 seconds will still have the same glitch). What might be causing this?

**EDIT**: Perhaps I should place both the `UIToolbar` and `UIDatePicker` in a new `UIView` container?

This is the code I'm using:

```
if ([self.view.subviews containsObject:self.dateRepeatPicker]) {

        [self dismissDateRepeatPickerSegmentChanged:NO];

         // "Hack", if I don't delay this call the UIToolbar will not display
         [self performSelector:@selector(showDatePicker) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.3];

} else if (![self.view.subviews containsObject:self.datePicker]) {

         [self showDatePicker];
}


- (void)dismissDateRepeatPickerSegmentChanged:(BOOL)segmentChanged {

    CGRect toolbarTargetFrame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height, 320, 44);
    CGRect dateRepeatPickerTargetFrame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height+44, 320, 216);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 

                     animations:^{
                         self.pickerToolbar.frame = toolbarTargetFrame;
                         self.dateRepeatPicker.frame = dateRepeatPickerTargetFrame;
                     }

                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                         if (segmentChanged) {

                             [self.pickerToolbar removeFromSuperview];
                             [self.dateRepeatPicker removeFromSuperview];
                             [self.remindMeTableView reloadData];

                         } else {

                             [self.pickerToolbar removeFromSuperview];
                             [self.dateRepeatPicker removeFromSuperview];
                         }

                     }];
}

- (void)showDatePicker {


    // Create the Toolbar over the Picker
    CGRect toolbarTargetFrame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height-216-44, 320, 44);

    if (self.pickerToolbar == nil) {

        self.pickerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height, 320, 44)];
        self.pickerToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
        self.pickerToolbar.translucent = YES;
    }

    UIBarButtonItem *spacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
    UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"picker-dismiss.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(dismissDatePickerToolbar)];
    [self.pickerToolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:spacer, doneButton, nil]];
    [self.view addSubview:self.pickerToolbar];


    // Create the Picker under the Toolbar
    CGRect datePickerTargetFrame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height-216, 320, 216);

    if (self.datePicker == nil) {

        self.datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height+44, 320, 216)];
        [self.datePicker setMinuteInterval:5];

        [self.datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(changeDate:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    }

    [self.view addSubview:self.datePicker];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{

        self.pickerToolbar.frame = toolbarTargetFrame;
        self.datePicker.frame = datePickerTargetFrame;

    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding the `UIPickerView` and the `UIToolbar` to a containing `UIView` and then animating the containing UIView.